# What's missing from my sftp chroot setup?

Tags: sftp, openssh, chroot

I've followed a half-dozen different tutorials on setting up chroot for sftp users, but my jailed users can still browse up into parent directories. I suspect my permissions aren't set up correctly, because this is the part that varies the most between the tutorials. Here's what I've done so far:

1) I'm using CentOS 5.6, where the default OpenSSH is version 4.3, so I manually installed the latest 5.x version. Running sshd -v now returns OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5.

2) I edited /etc/ssh/sshd_config to change Subsystem sftp to internal-sftp, and added:

```
Match user guest
ChrootDirectory %h
X11Forwarding no    
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

3) Restarted sshd.

4) Created a user "guest" with home directory /var/www/uploads/guest.

5) /var/www/uploads is owned by root:root with mode 755.

6) /var/www/uploads/guest is owned by guest:root with mode 755.

Using the Transmit sftp client on my Mac, I logged in with the guest user. It opens the user's home directory by default, but I can then navigate up the directory levels and browse other directories on the server.

Some tutorials say /var/www/uploads should have mode 700 or 750; if I do this, I can still log in as the guest user, but I see the server root directory by default and can browse all other directories.

Other tutorials say I should change the guest user's shell to /bin/false; if I do this, I can't log in as the guest user at all. Transmit says "The user name or password was not accepted by the server" and the command-line sftp client says "Connection closed" after I enter the password.

I think I've tried everything -- can someone see what's missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the ChrootDirectory should point to one level ABOVE the home directory.

So since guest's home is */var/www/uploads/guest*, then the **ChrootDirectory** should point to **/var/www/uploads**

That's a MAYBE.... another thought occurred to me:

You manually installed the newer openssh, did you remove the old version?  Where did the new version get installed?   *sometimes*, if you're not careful, new stuff will get installed into **/usr/local/** instead of **/usr**, meaning the sftp enabled server is reading its config files from */usr/local/etc/ssh/...* instead of the expected */etc/ssh/...*

Something to check at least.

Comment: You got it! My new installation of sshd put the binary in the same place as before, but put the config file into /usr/etc instead of /etc/ssh, so I was editing a config file that was no longer used. Although /etc/ssh is the location referenced by all tutorials and by the man page, I couldn't find a config option that would use that location, so I just made my updates to the new config file and now things are working as expected.

Comment: By the way, I did need to set up the directories so that the user's home directory is inside the chroot directory. I had tried that earlier, but since the chroot wasn't enabled at all, it didn't seem to make a difference. I did not, however, need to change the user's shell since that is disabled automatically when chrooting, although I suppose it wouldn't hurt.

Comment: No idea, but certainly pretty easy to test.  Glad you got it figured out.  (The 'command' you're looking for was probably a --prefix= option on the configure command, I'd have to look it up for sure though)

Comment: Yes, I had tried several values for --prefix, but couldn't find a value that would put both the binaries and the config file into their original locations. I found one tutorial mentioning that the default location of sshd_config is different in newer versions, but the man pages still refer to /etc/ssh. I suppose I could post this as a separate question, but I'm satisfied with my current setup.

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with the exact same problem, but solved it by setting up the chrooted directory ***as well as all parent directories*** with the following permissions

1) Changing owner to root:

```
sudo chown root [directory]
```

2) Removing all group write permissions:

```
sudo chmod 755 [directory]
```

Sadly I think that means you can't directly jump to a folder not owned by root, but will be happy to hear if anyone can correct me on this!

Comment: Not only must all parent directories be owned by root, but their group must also be root, for all directories in the path.